# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.checkpoint.CheckpointNotifier while consuming a kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using the latest Flink-1.1.2-Hadoop-27 and flink-connector-kafka-0.10.2-hadoop1 jars.

Flink consumer is as below:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env=StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        if (properties == null) {
            properties = new Properties();
            InputStream props = Resources.getResource(KAFKA_CONFIGURATION_FILE).openStream();
            properties.load(props);

            DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer082<>(KAFKA_SIP_TOPIC, new SimpleStringSchema() , properties));
```

Following is the exception I get after executing:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/api/checkpoint/CheckpointNotifier
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at com.bt.oss.voice.main.FlnkConsumer.main(FlnkConsumer.java:50)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.checkpoint.CheckpointNotifier
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 25 more
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mixing versions. A Kafka consumer for Flink 0.10.2 will not work with Flink 1.1.2.

You should use the Kafka connector provided with Flink 1.1.2 and include the following Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.8_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Please check out the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.1/apis/streaming/connectors/kafka.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

In case using [sbt](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/projectsetup/dependencies.html), the following update in flink scala dependencies solved my issue.

```
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided",
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided",
```

to:

```
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion,
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion,
```