# Flink with Kafka connection

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api, flink-streaming

Environment:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Flink 1.1.3
Kakfa 0.10.1.1
```

I'm trying to connect flink with kafka (Flink 1.1.3 Kakfa 0.10.1.1)
I already try all the fixes that i could find, but none of them work.

**pom.xml :**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ux</groupId>
<artifactId>logs</artifactId>
<version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Flink Quickstart Job</name>
<url>http://www.myorganization.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <flink.version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</flink.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>apache.snapshots</id>
        <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.10_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>build-jar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
                <version>${flink.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>${flink.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>${flink.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactSet>
                                    <excludes combine.self="override"></excludes>
                                </artifactSet>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-annotations</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-hadoop2</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-curator-recipes</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-core</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-scala_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-runtime_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-optimizer_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-clients_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-avro_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-examples-batch_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-examples-streaming_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-scala_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-scala-shell_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-python</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-metrics-core</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-metrics-jmx</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-statebackend-rocksdb_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>log4j:log4j</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-library</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-compiler</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-reflect</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.data-artisans:flakka-actor_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.data-artisans:flakka-remote_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.data-artisans:flakka-slf4j_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>io.netty:netty-all</exclude>
                                <exclude>io.netty:netty</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.avro:avro</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-collections:commons-collections</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-compress</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.tukaani:xz</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.objenesis:objenesis</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.twitter:chill_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.twitter:chill-java</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-lang:commons-lang</exclude>
                                <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-lang3</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-api</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12</exclude>
                                <exclude>log4j:log4j</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-math</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.commons.json</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-logging:commons-logging</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-codec:commons-codec</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations</exclude>
                                <exclude>stax:stax-api</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.typesafe:config</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.uncommons.maths:uncommons-maths</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.github.scopt:scopt_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-io:commons-io</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-cli:commons-cli</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>org.apache.flink:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org/apache/flink/shaded/com/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>web-docs/**</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

my java code :

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer010;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;

public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "flink_consumer");

        DataStream<String> messageStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<>
            ("ux_logs", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));

        messageStream.rebalance().map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -6867736771747690202L;

            public String map(String value) throws Exception {
                return "Kafka and Flink says: " + value;
            }
        }).print();

        env.execute();
    }
}
```

But I get this **error:**

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/api/checkpoint/CheckpointedFunction
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at ux.App.main(App.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:509)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:403)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:320)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:777)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:253)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1005)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1048)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.checkpoint.CheckpointedFunction
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Do i need to remove my kafka, and run an older version?
Is my flink kafka connector wrong?
i tried to use this plugin but it didn't work. (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/linking.html)

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately flink 1.1.x does not provide consumer for kafka 0.10. Fortunately though Flink 1.2.0 does. So try to upgrade flink version to 1.2.0. Also change the flink-kafka connector version to 1.2.0.

Answer (score 2):

You have to downgrade your connector:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.8_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40037895/1252056

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I already tired that fix before but I get this error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/api/checkpoint/CheckpointNotifier

Answer (score 2):

If you want to connect to Kafka 0.10~ you will have to move to Flink 1.2, otherwise, as @streetturte mentioned, you will have to downgrade your Kafka connector.

Have a look at the reference table here:

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/connectors/kafka.html

Answer (score 0):

Kafka 0.9 and newer version don't need to zookeeper.
You need to upgrade your flink or downgrade Kafka version

```
--topic myTopic --bootstrap.servers 10.123.34.56:9092 --group.id myGroup

FlinkKafkaConsumer09<CarDB> consumerBinden = new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<CarDB>(
                kafkaTopic,
                new ClassClassSchema(),
                parameterTool.getProperties());


<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
   <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What is the zookeeper?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are using Flink-Kafka consumer dependency for Scala in your pom file, whereas your code is in Java. Try flink kafka consumer for Java in your pom. Hope it helps.